# Как в Python & tkinter при использовании MVC создать главное окно программы?

Tags: python, mvc, tkinter

Пытаюсь реализовать шаблон MVC для приложения по примеру

https://github.com/li360/tkinter-mvc

В классе, отвечающим за создание главного окна приложения не знаю какие параметры использовать, - не отображаются элементы окна.

В примере 2 окна обмениваются данными, поэтому у них родительский класс выбран Toplevel. Но Toplevel не позволяет использовать вложенные элементы, такие как меню, ttk.Notebook и пр. и его рекомендуется использовать для диалоговых окон.

Как я понимаю, что происходит:

1. В main.py создается объект контроллера, ему передается ссылка на главное окно приложения, созданное с помощью root = Tk() => app = Controller(root).
2. В сонтроллере MainController.py создается объект окна self.view_main_window = ViewMainWindow(root) которому, в свою очередь, передается ссылка на главное окно приложения уже из класса контроллера.
3. MainView.py получает ссылку в конструкторе def **init**(self, parent), переименовывает self.master = parent. Дальше виджеты используют ее для определения своей принадлежности.

Это в теории, на практике, - после запуска окна нет, но и сообщений об ошибках тоже нет.

```
main.py
from tkinter import *
from controllers.MainController import Controller

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("PyDOE-tk")
    root.withdraw()
    app = Controller(root)
    root.mainloop()


controllers/MainController.py
from models.MainModel import Model
from views.MainView import ViewMainWindow

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view_main_window = ViewMainWindow(root) 


views/MainView.py
from tkinter import *

class ViewMainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.master = parent                    
        self.frame = Frame()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.button = Button(self.frame, text="myButton")
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.name = Label(self.frame, text='Label')
        self.name.pack()
```

Если выбрать родительским классом Toplevel (как в примере на github), то окно показывается, но пустое:

```
class ViewMainWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.master = parent
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.master.destroy)                    
        self.frame = Frame()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.button = Button(self.frame, text="myButton")
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.name = Label(self.frame, text='Label')
        self.name.pack()
```

**PS 1**:
*Выполнил рекомендации из первого комментария. Если сделать файл исполняемым, как в примере ниже, то все работает. Отображается окно с кнопкой и текстом.
Так я это и так понимаю, ведь у меня и вопрос сформулирован: какие параметры нужно передать из файла точки запуска через контроллер, что бы окно появилось с содержимым.*

```
from tkinter import *
class ViewMainWindow:
    def __init__(self, parent):        
        self.master = parent        
        self.frame = Frame()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.button = Button(self.frame, text="myButton")
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.name = Label(self.frame, text='Label')
        self.name.pack()
        self.master.mainloop()

root = Tk()
ViewMainWindow(root)
```

**PS 2**:
Думал, что как то ссылка на главное окно не передается, ввел строку

```
print('type of root: ', type(parent), id(parent))
```

в main, контроллер и представление, оказалось, что ссылка на главное окно передается одна и та же:

```
type of root from main:  <class 'tkinter.Tk'> 2774823903920
type of root from controller:  <class 'tkinter.Tk'> 2774823903920
type of root from view:  <class 'tkinter.Tk'> 2774823903920
```

Answer (score 1):

**Разобрался**.

В примере на github показано взаимодействие двух окон, что несколько специфично, обычно большая часть действий выполняется в главном окне программы. Но поскольку там так задумано (в одном окне две кнопки, изменяющие значение лейбла в другом окне) для реализации независимых окон автору пришлось использовать окна `Toplevel`. Вот немного о них:

> *Марк Лутц Программирование на Python том I:* Обычно окна `Toplevel`
>   используются для реализации многооконных интерфейсов, а также
>   модальных и немодальных диалогов. Они сохраняются до тех пор, пока не будут явно закрыты или пока создавшее их приложение не завершит работу.

Сколько я не пробовал менять параметры передачи ссылки на главное окно ничего не получалось, пока я не обратил внимание на метод `root.withdraw()` в файле `main.py`. Несмотря на название, оказалось, что он скрывает окно:

> `withdraw()` Removes the window from the screen (without destroying it).
>   To redraw the window, use deiconify. When the window has been
>   withdrawn, the state method returns “withdrawn”.

Но в примере он нужен, что бы скрыть пустое нефункциональное окно root, которое заменяют два независимых окна `Toplevel`. В моем случае - приложение будет однооконное, поэтому если убрать этот метод, то все сразу начинает работать.

Рабочий файл `main.py` выглядит так:

```
main.py
from tkinter import *
from controllers.MainController import Controller

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("PyDOE-tk")    
    app = Controller(root)
    root.mainloop()
```